# CMD window minimized for Popen() call?

Tags: python, windows, automation, pywin32

I'm using Popen() to start a windows application and there is a windows CMD console that pops up, which I need to monitor the standard input/output. Is there a way that this CMD window can be minimized immediately? The console window itself is interfering with the app the Popen() starts because it obscures the visible desktop.

I'm on winXP 32 with Python 2.6.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you starting the application from a CMD console? in this case no new console window should open...

Comment: No. the process is triggered by another application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the CMD console has a non-ambiquous title, you can get a handle to it and minimize it with the following (just after the process has launched):

```
import win32gui
handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, cmd_window_title)
win32gui.ShowWindow(handle, 6)
```

6 is for `SW_MINIMIZE` (See [MSDN doc for the ShowWindow() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548))

Of course you should add appropriate checks, like wait for the window to appear, etc.

Comment: You can use `win32con.SW_MINIMIZE` instead of `6`

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the extension of your python file to .pyw?, with pyw the python interpreter doesn't  show the windows console, and about the stdot/stdin  you can use subprocess.PIPE with

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen('program.exe', shell=true,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
 #read stdout
 print cmd.stdout.read()
 #write stdin
 cmd.stdin.write('DATA')
```

or use `Popen.communicate` http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects

Comment: This is a good suggestion, except that it's convenient to have the minimized window in the system tray so I can inspect the various messages they get written there. Also, it's easier to kill a process that you can reach from the system tray.

Answer (score 0):

The following will minimize a newly created application based on its pid.

Answer based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4875055/3061838 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44736622/3061838.

```
import win32process
import win32gui
import win32con
import time


def minimize_cb(handle, pid):
    ''' Call back function used by minimize'''
    __, processId = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle)
    if processId == pid:
        win32gui.ShowWindow(handle, win32con.SW_MINIMIZE)


def minimize(pid):
    '''Minimize window'''
    try:
        win32gui.EnumWindows(minimize_cb, pid)
    except Exception as e:
        print('minimize failed', e)


proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
# you may need to wait a little before the window is created
# sorry I don't have a better method...
time.sleep(1)
minimize(proc.pid)
```