# pywin32: how to get window handle from process handle and vice versa

Tags: winapi, pywin32

Two use-cases:

1. Enumerate windows and then get the process handle for each window
2. Enumerate processes and then get the main application window handle for each process

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Enumerate windows and then get the process handle for each window

You need these APIs:

- [`win32gui.EnumWindows()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__EnumWindows_meth.html) to enumerate all top-level windows (that is no child windows aka controls)
- [`win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process__GetWindowThreadProcessId_meth.html) to get process ID from window handle
- [`win32api.OpenProcess()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__OpenProcess_meth.html) to get process handle from process ID

> Enumerate processes and then get the main application window handle
> for each process

You need these APIs:

- [`win32process.EnumProcesses()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32process__EnumProcesses_meth.html) to enumerate all processes
- [`win32api.GetWindowLong()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetWindowLong_meth.html) with argument `GWL_STYLE` to get [window styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) and `GWL_EXSTYLE` to get [extended window styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar#managing-taskbar-buttons)
- [`win32gui.GetParent()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__GetParent_meth.html) to determine unowned windows

By filtering the result of `EnumWindows()` using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` you can get all windows that belong to a given process.

Determining the *main window* can be tricky as there is no single window style that would designate a window as the *main window*. After all, an application might have **multiple** *main windows*.

Best you could do is to use the same rules that the [taskbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar) uses to determine application windows, because that's what the user perceives as *main windows*:

> The Shell places a button on the taskbar whenever an application
> creates an unowned window—that is, a window that does not have a
> parent and that has the appropriate extended style bits.

> To ensure that the window button is
> placed on the taskbar, create an unowned window with the
> WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style. To prevent the window button from
> being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the
> WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW extended style. As an alternative, you can create a
> hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible
> window.

Use `GetParent()` and `GetWindowLong()` to determine the unowned windows that have the right window styles according to these rules.